# Is there maybe third part or boost similar, map with same interface like from stl but thread safe?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I have lot of threads ( which produce request objects) and I have one working thread which for every request produce response. I am using map to with key is id of one producer and value is thread safe queue so I can from working thread based on id push to appropriate queue.
I found this implementation of thread safe map which holds pairs id,shared queue. My problem is ( I don't have lot of experience with multithreading) how to from worker thread read all queues for all keys. 
I can try with wait_and_pop or implement method which just returns list of all shared pointers to queues, unlock and then iterate. Is there maybe third part or boost simililar, map with same interface like from stl but thread safe ?

```
#ifndef THREADSAFE_MAP_HPP
#define THREADSAFE_MAP_HPP


    #include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
    #include <boost/thread/recursive_mutex.hpp>
    #include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
    #include <boost/thread/condition_variable.hpp>

    #include <map>


    template<typename Key, typename Data>
    class ConcurrentMap
    {
    public:
        ConcurrentMap(void){};
        ~ConcurrentMap(void){};

        void clear() {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mMutex);
            mQueue.clear();
        }

        bool contains(Key const& key) {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mMutex);
            typename std::map<Key, Data>::iterator itr = mQueue.find(key);
            return (itr != mQueue.end());
        }

        bool erase(Key const& key) {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mMutex);
            size_t n = mQueue.erase(key);
            return (n > 0);
        }

        void push(Key const& key, Data const& data) {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mMutex);
            mQueue[key] = data;
            lock.unlock();
            mCondition.notify_one();
        }

        bool empty() const {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mMutex);
            return mQueue.empty();
        }

        bool get(Key const& key, Data& popped_value) {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mMutex);
            typename std::map<Key, Data>::iterator itr = mQueue.find(key);
            if (itr == mQueue.end())
                return false;

            popped_value = mQueue[key];
            return true;
        }

        bool try_pop(Key const& key, Data& popped_value) {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mMutex);

            typename std::map<Key, Data>::iterator itr = mQueue.find(key);
            if (itr == mQueue.end())
                return false;

            popped_value = mQueue[key];
            mQueue.erase(key);

            return true;
        }

        void wait_and_pop(Key const& key, Data& popped_value) {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mMutex);
            typename std::map<Key, Data>::iterator itr;
            while(mQueue.find(key) == mQueue.end()) {
                mCondition.wait(lock);
            }

            popped_value = mQueue[key];
            mQueue.erase(key);
        }

    private:
        std::map<Key, Data> mQueue;
        mutable boost::mutex    mMutex;
        boost::condition_variable   mCondition;
    };

    #endif // THREADSAFE_MAP_HPP
```

Comment: There's also the [Parallel Patterns Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504906.aspx) from Microsoft.

Comment: @Praetorian Code is deployed on CentOS Linux.

Comment: TBB supports Linux, look at the linked dupe.